# Moving Google Resource Calendar to Exchange

Tags: exchange, calendar, google-workspace, office365

I've been searching and coming up blank in this regard. How can I move/migrate the calendar entries that's on our Google Apps resource/room calendar to a Microsoft Exchange/Office 365 calendar?

Answer (score 1):

> If you'd like to migrate your events from another calendar service,
>   click the name of the calendar you've been using. Below are
>   instructions on how to import these events to Google Calendar from a
>   few other calendar services.
>
> 1. Open Outlook
> 2. Click Calendar
> 3. Right click on the calendar you need to export and choose Save as
> 4. Select type iCalendar format
> 5. Click on More Options and select Date Range -> Whole calendar, Detail -> Full details
> 6. Click OK and then Save
> 7. In Google Calendar, click the down-arrow next to Other calendars
> 8. Select Import calendar
> 9. Click Choose file and find the file that contains your events, then click Open
> 10. Select the Google Calendar where you'd like to import events, then click Import
>
> The exported file doesn't support recurring Outlook events. Individual
>   items will be created for recurring events that fall between the dates
>   you've selected.

[Source](http://support.google.com/calendar/answer/83126)